# Which types of matrices conserve the gradient operator?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, scalar-fields

Let $M \in \Bbb R^{3 \times 3}$. Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain and $u :\Omega \to \mathbb R$ be an infinitely-differentiable scalar field. What conditions should matrix $M$ satisfy to ensure the existence of a scalar field $v : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ such that

$$M\nabla u=\nabla v$$

In such a case, can we give an explicit expression of $v$ which depend on $M$ and $u$? Thanks.

Comment: Does the Cauchy Kowalevski theorem answer your question?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Kowalevski_theorem

Comment: @AlexR. Wouldn't we need $u$ to be analytic for the Cauchy-Kowalevski theorem to apply?

Comment: @AlexR. It's a more general theorem, I couldn't see how I could apply it?

Comment: I added a missed detail: $u$ is a real-valued function defined on $\Omega$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The given function is $u$ and the unknown one is $v: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ .

Comment: [Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology))

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedoYes, I agree with your edits. I will take a look at this theorem and try to find a solution

Comment: I would focus on $n=2$ first. Post your work on the question itself. It's hard to be motivated to do work when the OP himself or herself is not.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I think it's the Poincaré lemma or the Schwarz one.